# Centralized control of javascript timer for many domains without using include?

Tags: javascript, css, timer

I have many pages from different domains. I would like to be able to control a Javascript timer centrally but without using javascript include. Using CSS include is OK (Maybe a CSS timer is possible?).

To me it seems impossible, but maybe someone has an idea how to do this without Javascript include. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Without include? Nest it in the html with `<script></script>`? And CSS is impossible.

Comment: Can't use iFrame or Javascript include. Probably this is something that can't be done. Basically I need the configuration for the Javascript to be remote, but the Javascript code can run on every domain. So how to make the configuration of the JS remote?

Comment: @sojim how is the time triggered? based on an event or based on a specific date/time?

Comment: @Skwal The time counts down to 4pm everyday except Sunday. (For an ecommerce site). I've got an idea, can javascript call an XML file for configuration?

Comment: @sojim Yes you can, do an ajax for that (after all the 'x' from ajax stands for XML). But since it's a countdown to a specific time, you could also just have a copy of the same script on each domain.

Comment: @Skwal I just found out that we can do a sort of "include" by using ``resource.src = http://www.test.com/test.js``

Comment: Well it's still an include, I thought that wasn't an option :)

Comment: @skwal I meant that in a literal sense :). I need to control it from a centralized location because sometimes the times change, for example some holidays happen on different dates, so the time needs to be changed yearly.